# Keras can't compute a graph node in a callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

To illustrate the issue, consider the (entirely artificial) example of a model below:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

class RandomSeq(Sequence):
    def __len__(self):
        return 5

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return (np.array([np.arange(39).reshape((39,)) for i in range(100)]), 
                np.array([-np.arange(39).reshape((39,)) for i in range(100)]))

class Foo(Callback):
    def __init__(self, d):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self._d = d

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print(epoch)
        print(K.eval(self._d))



x = Input(shape=(39,), dtype='float32', name='input')
y_pred = Dense(39)(x)

y_another = x * 2

m = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y_pred)
m.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

seq = RandomSeq()
m.fit_generator(seq, epochs=5, callbacks=[Foo(y_another)])
```

`RandomSeq` is just a sequence that returns `x` and `y` batches. `Foo` is a callback that will try to evaluate the attached quantity `d` at the end of an epoch. For me, if I choose `d` to be `y_pred` or `y_another`, then Keras complains that the placeholder `x` (`input`) is not fed.

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,39]

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there another way to compute a node in a Keras callback? Note that the example works fine if there's no callback that computes the mentioned graph nodes.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way for doing it. 
Running K.eval(y_another) you are asking keras backend to evaluate an Input object (which is only a placeholder for the data you want to feed into the network) without feeding it with any data, that's the reason of your error.

Thus, assuming that you want to compute the output of the network given a new input that is a random sequence multiplied by 2 (is this right?), then you should modify the body of `on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None)` in your callback as follow:

```
x, _ = next(RandomSeq())     
print(self.model.predict(x*2))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Like I said, the example is entirely artificial and serves no purpose other than highlighting the issue. It is however a proxy for a more elaborate graph I'm working with. So, you can imagine that the branch that computes `y_another` might as well be a sequence of custom layers, which would need to be specified before model compilation. Since those layers will be tied to the placeholder in my graph, I guess the question becomes how can I feed the placeholder in the callback so that the edge node in the other branch may be computed?

Comment: So if I understand well, y_another consume the same input but implements a different architecture, right? in this case you should add ``y_another`` to the model output Model(inputs=x, outputs=[y_pred, y_another] and in the callback, instead of using K.eval, just run ``self.model.predict(inputs)`` and you will receive both outputs

Comment: That's what I thought too. But if it's something that doesn't count towards the loss and nothing in this branch should be optimized, how do I control that? It also  makes logic in my sequence a bit weird since now I should return ground truth for this new output as well when there is none.

Comment: If you don't want to optimise over that additional output, then I don't understand why you want to compute that value inside a network. If you just want to run computation on gpu I recommend you to use tensorflow instead of keras. On the other hand if the operation is very simple, you can just use numpy.

Comment: Well it's a matplotlib plot converted to a tensor using tfmpl. I intend to write it as a summary so that it can be visualized in tensorboard. It's a visualization of a Kinect skeleton btw.

Comment: If the summary you want to write is just a scalar you can do it easily without converting it into a tensor `summary = tf.Summary(value[tf.Summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])`
For other type of summaries you can look at this link https://gist.github.com/gyglim/1f8dfb1b5c82627ae3efcfbbadb9f514